# git stash show -p: hide gitignored files

Tags: git, gitignore, git-stash

When I use stash, I run `git stash -u` so that all files are stashed.

When I want to look at the stash contents using `git stash show -p`, it will also include in the diff files which are in my `.gitignore` list. This is understandable, since `-p` stands for "patch", but is there a way to ask git to not show these gitignored files in the stash show -p output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems `git diff stash@{0}^..stash@{0}` is what I want. Or change to any other stash ID of course.